# Reddish areas in lightmap

Tags: light, texture-baking, baking

I am trying to bake a lightmap in Blender 2.8. To archive this, I created a new UV layer and a new texture. I then baked a Diffuse Map (influenced by Direct and Indirect, not Color). However, I'm not satisfied with the outcome. There are some reddish areas I can't explain. Does somebody know how to get rid of them?

Best regards

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. You are wrongly assuming that indirect light can't be colored (that's only the direct light that is splitted in color and intensity), while most of the time is. It's the light that has bounced onto the surfaces that surrounds your object. Check them.

Comment: @Carlo Turning off indirect lighting did indeed solve my problem. Thank you very much. If you like to post your suggestion as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll do as soon as possible. I'm glad it helped you.